# HVAC - hot air flowing on both zones when only 1 zone should be on

Tags: hvac, heating, ventilation, central-heating, troubleshooting

I have 2-zone forced air heating, with separate thermostats for each zone.  Normally, if the thermostat in zone 1 triggers the system to go on, the heat will only blow through the vents in zone 1.  Now, when the thermostat in zone 1 triggers the system to go on, heat blows through the vents in *both* zone 1 *and* zone 2, not just in zone 1.  What's wrong?

Comment: What model thermostats, zone controller, and furnace/AC do you have?

Comment: Have you checked the damper(s), to verify they're opening/closing when they should. Could be that zone 2 is stuck open.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel:  I'll check that info when I get home tonight, and add it to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Tester101:  I haven't checked that.  I'll have to see if I can figure that out tonight.  Thanks.

Comment: Tester101:  You were right - the gear between the damper motor and the damper vents was worn.  Thanks for the tip!!